# Mean of dependent variable is not constant in simple linear regression

Tags: regression

I am just trying to understand simple linear regression and I am not understanding why $\bar y$ is not constant. Doesn't $\bar y$ means means of all $y_i$'s and mean of anything is constant, no? I am not from math background so please bear with me. I am referring to regression line: $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon$

By $\bar y$ I mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i$/n.

I got confused because of below two reasons:

1. To prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \bar y(x_i - \bar x) = 0$ we pull out $\bar y$ out of summation. We can pull it out of summation only when $\bar y$ is not dependent on $i$.
2. But on other hand ${\rm Cov}(y_i,\bar y)$ is not zero. If $\bar y$ is constant then ${\rm Cov}(y_i,\bar y)$ should have been zero.

Can someone please explain me this?

Comment: What do you have in mind when you are talking about $\bar y$ ...? If it is $1/n \sum_i y_i$, then how exactly does it relate to linear regression? Please edit your question to make it more precise, since otherwise this is a guessing game.

Comment: Since the y$_i$ are random variables the average is also a random variable even though for any fixed sample it is constant.

Comment: @Tim - Yes, I meant mean.

Comment: @MayankJain so how does it relate to linear regression? Unless you have in mind the $y_i = \beta_0 + \varepsilon$ model, it does not estimate the global mean.

Comment: @Tim - Because It is mean of $y_i$'s, which is in context to SLR.

Comment: In linear regression the sample mean is not an estimated parameter but the least squares regression line does pass through the point mean of x with the mean of y.  The question is clear even though it applies more generally then in linear regression. Also I think my initial comment answers the question.

Comment: @MayankJain You need to edit your question to tell us more on what you understand and what is unclear for you.

Comment: @MichaelChernick - When you say that average is random variable, it is function of which variables?

Comment: @Tim - I tried adding something more to the question.

Comment: It is a function of the y$_i$s which are all random variables. For example if the y$_i$s are iid N(0,1) the sample mean is N(0, 1/n).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "To prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \bar y(x_i - \bar x)$"? That is just a quantity; there is nothing there to be proven. Regarding your #2, $Cov(y_i,\bar y)$ *is* $0$, so I don't quite follow your point. You don't have to have a complete or correct understanding of these topics to ask about them here--that's what we're here for! But your question does need to be clear enough for people to make sense of, so that we can be sure the information we provide is the answer to your question. Can you clarify this any further?

Comment: @gung If we're treating the $y$'s as representing random variables (rather than as representing observations) $\text{Cov}(y_1,(y_1+y_2+y_3))$ isn't zero, it's $\text{Var}(y_1)$ Covariance of $\bar{y}$ and $y_i$ works similarly